# Do quest items despawn when the person quits the game?

Tags: sea-of-thieves

While playing Sea of Theives, my friends and I saw a sloop on a nearby island, and wanted to go say "hi".

He didn't see us approach, he was on the island doing a quest. I jumped on his boat and stole the most expensive looking thing I could find, which was a named chest that contained a skull with blue crystals coming out the top. We left without sinking his ship.

My friends told me we couldn't actually sell the skull, it was purely for quest purposes. So we thought at least it would look better as a decoration on our mast for the session rather than as a completed quest for that guy.

But then the skull disappeared and we were all sad, but the empty chest remained on our boat.

We hypothesized that the guy signed out and the quest item went with him. Could that be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are exactly right.  The item you are talking about is a Tall Tale item for "The Revenge of the Morningstar" and this skull along with another item is used to spawn the boss.  Since it is not an item you can actually sell it de-spawned since they left but the chest stays because you can continue to use it like the regular collectors chests.  You can also sell the chest.

Comment: I think you got a typo. Are you trying to tell me I can "sell it de-spawed"?